# Codenameone Layered Layout

Tags: codenameone

I have two containers on a layered layout say c1 and c2.
c1 has a lot of buttons, drag n drop etc.
c2 has a translucent background for the entire screen with a centre aligned image and a close button.

I need to be able to automatically disable all actions for c1 when c2 is added over c1.
While I can handle this programatically when c2 is added over c1 during runtime, it would great to automatically disable all events for c1.

Is there a better way to handle this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think making the top layer focusable should grab the events from the underlying component. Haven't tested it though.

Comment: It didnt work. i tried rubrics_cntnr.setFocusable(true);
                            rubrics_cntnr.requestFocus();

Comment: You don't need the request focus, just the setFocusable. If that container is on top in terms of z-order (last added) it should grab the pointer events.

Comment: I did that and the container was on top, but the bottom layer is still taking events

Comment: We just tested this with a simple test case and events aren't delivered to the container below. I suggest you check your code.