# How to enable two components layed out with LayeredLayout to both receive events?

Tags: codenameone

I'm using a LayeredLayout to overlay a TextArea with a small button in the upper right-hand corner of the TextArea (the button is used to insert a time-stamp to easily date the manual text entries).

I want the small button to receive the events when the user 'clicks' on it and at also allow the user to click in the TextArea below to edit the text manually. However, when I use LayeredLayout, only that last added component will receive the events. Meaning either only the textArea is active and the small button cannot be pushed, or the button can be pushed, but the user cannot click the TextArea to initiate the edit. Hope the description is clear enough to understand.

As far as I could see, none of the other existing Layouts lends themselves to this case. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both receive events when clicked, we use this pattern often. I'm assuming you tried to push the button while you were editing which is problematic since editing delegates pointer events to the native OS editing code.

See:

```
Form current = new Form("TextAreaButton", BoxLayout.y());

TextArea ta = new TextArea("Text of Text Area");
ta.addActionListener(e -> Log.p("Text is: " + ta.getText()));
Button b = new Button("");
b.addActionListener(e -> ta.setText(""));
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(b, FontImage.MATERIAL_CLEAR);
current.add(
        LayeredLayout.encloseIn(ta,
                BorderLayout.east(b))
);

current.show();
```

Comment: (Partly) my bad. Probably due to the button no being clickable once you're editing the textArea, I had experimented and added a statement for the setFocusable(true) button container. And I'd seen this page which seemed to confirm that only the top layer would grab the events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852251/codenameone-layered-layout.

Comment: The challenge is still that it's pretty bad ergonomics (unintuitive) that the button becomes ineffective when you start editing. But maybe a solution could be shorten the TextArea and place the button outside, and wrap both in a container with TextArea UIID to make it seem like the button is inside the TextArea. I'll try that.

Comment: Yes that's a valid workaround. Text input is a pretty special case. I'm assuming your use case is the X button at the edge, there is an RFE to add that natively into Codename One as this is something that should be addressed by the platform

Comment: I think to you refer to an RFE I submitted some time back. However, the above use case is not about deleting the text but having the button insert text (a time stamp preceding a manual text entry). But for deletion it is probably worse ergonomics that once you start editing the delete button becomes ineffective. Impossible for the user to understand, and no way to explain/defend other than by referring to technical limitations in CN1.

Comment: I just tried the workaround. Some tweaking of margin/padding is needed to make it appear as if the button is (almost) inside the TextArea but workable. However, not obvious to me how to ensure that the surrounding Container uses the TextArea selected style when the TextArea inside is being edited?

Comment: You can use lead component to create a single component and exclude that specific button from the lead https://www.codenameone.com/blog/unleading-mutating-accordion.html . I think you would have problems doing it in native too since it would be hard to distinguish between selection gestures in text editing and button press.