# How to handle components click event on CodenameOne Layered Container

Tags: layout, codenameone

Please I am currently facing a challenges with layered ayout. I have a container with a layeredlayout and added many container on top of it like a stacked card I want each stack card to be clickable, so I decided set a Lead component on each card but the response I am getting when any of the container is clicked are the same.
I have also try to setleadcomponet on the main Container (with layeredLayout) but the responese I am getting is for only the container that was added last.

Comment: please take refer of this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852251/codenameone-layered-layout

Answer (score 0):

Lead component does the exact opposite of what it seems you are trying to do. It delegates all events to one component within the hierarchy.

Events in Codename One are sent to one Component in the hierarchy so regardless of that the layered layout has nothing to do with even delivery. The foremost focusable component will get the event. You can do various tricks to allow elaborate event delivery but you might need to rephrase the question explaining what you are trying to do and not how you expect something to work.

Comment: Shai, what I am trying to do is to have a list of containers layered on top each other with certain margin above each other. So whenever a user clicked on any one of the container, I wanted to get that selected container. The Containers has the same width and height, the last added is entirely visible, why others are only visible through the margin from set by the second. Please just need a way to achieve this layered container things. Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the layered layout sample in the kitchen sink demo under layouts?

Comment: Yes, I did and the question is how do you handle click event when any of the component (of the Main Layout container) is cicked or pressed. For examle using the KitchenSink Demo, when I added 'addPointerReleasedListener' to each Component only the first component is resonding to 'PointerReleased' event. Thanks

Comment: Only one component will always respond to the event otherwise it wouldn't make sense. You'd click a button on top of the map and something will popup in the map too. I'm guessing that this isn't really what you want... If you want that you can just override the pointer events in one component and broadcast those to the other component too.